# Trouble installing cmake on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu, cmake

For some reason I decided it would be a good idea to `apt-get remove cmake` from my ubuntu 12.04 distro and then put it back, but when I do `sudo apt-get install cmake` I get the following error:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 cmake : Depends: cmake-data (= 2.8.7-0ubuntu5) but 2.8.11.2-1ubuntu2~precise1 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I have also tried to install cmake according to [this](http://www.geeksww.com/tutorials/operating_systems/linux/installation/downloading_compiling_and_installing_cmake_on_linux.php) guide, which appeared to have completed successfully, but still no cmake.  I get

```
bash: /usr/bin/cmake: No such file or directory
```

What would cause this issue and how can I fix it?

Comment: did you create the `/usr/bin/cmake` folder and then try it?

Answer (score 0):

The link provided in the question sets the build directory in the configure to `/opt/cmake`, and as noted in that discussion, cmake can be ran as

```
$/opt/cmake/bin/cmake
```

You can copy the `/opt/cmake/bin/cmake` to the `/bin/` directory, or add the `/opt/cmake/bin/` directory to your `$PATH` environment variable to be able to use cmake as

```
$cmake
```

As for the dependency issue, it's currently still a mystery.